# Martingale in steps.

Tags: probability, statistics, martingales, signal-processing

I have a discrete-time process that satisfies for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\forall n_0<n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_k<n\in \mathbb{Z}: \ \  E[X[n+1]|X[n],X[n_k],X[n_{k-1}],\ldots , X[n_0]]=X[n]$$
I want to show that $X[n]$ is a martingale, i.e. that it satisfies:
$$\forall n_0<n_1<n_2<\ldots <n_k<n\in \mathbb{Z}:\ \  E[X[n+1]|X[n_k],X[n_{k-1}],\ldots,X[n_0]]=X[n_k]$$.

So I am suggested to prove it by induction on $m$ where $n_k=n-m$.
The base step of the induction is easily satisfied since for $m=0$ we get from the definition of $X[n]$ that: $E[X[n+1]|X[n_k],X[n_{k-1}],\ldots, X[n_0]]=E[X[n+1]|X[n_k],X[n_k],X[n_{k-1}],\ldots, X[n_0]]=X[n_k]$.

But I don't see how to prove the induction step:
Suppose it's satisfied for $m$ and prove it for $m+1$, i.e:
$$E[X[n+1]|X[n-m],X[n_{k-1}],\ldots, X[n_0]]=X[n_k]=X[n-m]$$
Now I need to show that: $E[X[n+1]|X[n-m-1],\ldots]=X[n-m-1]$, but I don't see how exactly.

Can you help me with this derivation?

Comment: Hi: Doesn't what you want to show follow from the first line of your question ? You can just replace $X[n]$ with $X[n - m -1]$.

Comment: @markleeds I don't think you can plug in first identity like you suggest. But I am not sure.

Comment: Hi: I'm not sure either. But the question is weird because the first line you wrote is the definition of a martingale. Someone else will hopefully give a better suggestion-answer.